# Sort is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I am trying to sort the date by `desc` wise. But getting wrong result. any one help me? Actually I am getting the date values by "DD/MM/YYYY"

here is my try:

```js
var sortDate = [
  "08/10/2017",
  "08/03/2017",
  "07/04/2017",
  "07/09/2016",
  "07/08/2017",
  "22/07/2017",
  "16/12/2017"
]

sortDate.sort(function(a,b){

  var aComps = a.split("/");
  var bComps = b.split("/");
  
 new Date( bComps[2] +"/"+ bComps[1] +"/"+ bComps[0]) - 
  new Date( aComps[2] +"/"+ aComps[1] +"/"+ aComps[0] )
  
})

console.log(sortDate)
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sw8v02e6/1/)

Comment: **1)** you are not returning anything **2)** do `return Date().getTime() - Date().getTime()`. In fact simple `return  (bComps[2] + bComps[1] + bComps[0]).localeCompare( (aComps[2] + aComps[1] + aComps[0]) )`

Comment: those strings are not Date objects @gurvinder372

Comment: that's what i am trying to convert them as date. if find any issue, pls correct me

Comment: personally, because Date parsing is so hit and miss ... and all your dates have leading zeros .... `return parseInt(bComps[2]+bComps[1]+bComps[0]) - parseInt(aComps[2]+aComps[1]+aComps[0]);`

Comment: @JaromandaX - not works your fix

Comment: @3gwebtrain - you did something wrong then, because it works 100%

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data is already seems to be having `0` prefix padding so the value of date and month would always be in 2 digits.

So, *No need to parse as Dates*, just do a **string comparison** using `localeCompare`

```
return  ( aComps[2] + aComps[1] + aComps[0] ).localeCompare( bComps[2] + bComps[1] + bComps[0] );
```

**Demo**

```js
var sortDate = [
  "08/10/2017",
  "08/03/2017",
  "07/04/2017",
  "07/09/2016",
  "07/08/2017",
  "22/07/2017",
  "16/12/2017"
]

sortDate.sort(function(a,b){
    var aComps = a.split("/");
    var bComps = b.split("/");
    return  ( aComps[2] + aComps[1] + aComps[0] ).localeCompare( bComps[2] + bComps[1] + bComps[0] );      
})

console.log(sortDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date string and use it with [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) for sorting.

```js
var sortDate = ["08/10/2017", "08/03/2017", "07/04/2017", "07/09/2016", "07/08/2017", "22/07/2017", "16/12/2017"];

sortDate.sort(function (a, b) {
    function getISO(s) {
        return s.replace(/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/, '$3-$2-$1');
    }

    return getISO(a).localeCompare(getISO(b));
});

console.log(sortDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the value from function :

```js
sortDate.sort(function(a,b){

  var aComps = a.split("/");
  var bComps = b.split("/");

   return  new Date( bComps[2] +"/"+ bComps[1] +"/"+ bComps[0]) - 
  new Date( aComps[2] +"/"+ aComps[1] +"/"+ aComps[0] )

})
```

Comment: What about the fact that the [strings won't parse as dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46949457/sort-is-not-working-properly#comment80846226_46949457)

Comment: Yeah string are not date object but at the end we are converting those string  in date object `new Date()` if you see.

Comment: Valid input for new Date is `(m)m/(d)d/(yy)yy`

Comment: and what happens if you do a `new Date("08/10/2017")`? is that 8th october or 10th of Aug? It depends on what country your in

Comment: @Liam, isn't the input set to `mm/dd/yyyy` by default regardless of region or `mm-dd-yyyy`?

Comment: @mouser or  `yyyy/(m)m/(d)d `

Comment: To [quote MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) *parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse, they are equivalent) is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies. Support for RFC 2822 format strings is by convention only. Support for ISO 8601 formats differs in that date-only strings (e.g. "1970-01-01") are treated as UTC, not local.*

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```js
var sortDate = [
  "08/10/2017",
  "08/03/2017",
  "07/04/2017",
  "07/09/2016",
  "07/08/2017",
  "22/07/2017",
  "16/12/2017"
]

sortDate.sort(function(a,b){

  var aComps = a.split("/").reverse().join("/");
  var bComps = b.split("/").reverse().join("/");
  
 return new Date(aComps) - 
  new Date(bComps )
  
})

console.log(sortDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
var sortDate = [
 "08/10/2017",
 "08/03/2017",
 "07/04/2017",
 "07/09/2016",
 "07/08/2017",
 "22/07/2017",
 "16/12/2017"
]

sortDate.sort(function(a,b){
var aComps = a.split("/");
var bComps = b.split("/");

var date1 = new Date();
var date2 = new Date();
console.log(a)
date1.setMonth(aComps[1]-1)
date1.setFullYear(aComps[2]);
date1.setDate(aComps[0]);
console.log(date1)
console.log(b)
date2.setMonth(bComps[1]-1)
date2.setFullYear(bComps[2]);
date2.setDate(bComps[0]);


console.log(date2)

return date2 - date1;

})

console.log(sortDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) but it slower than simple comparison of strings.

You could use [String.prototype.localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) but it much more slower then numbers comparison.

**So to make it works and optimize your function** you could do:

```js
var dates = [
  "08/10/2017",
  "08/03/2017",
  "07/04/2017",
  "07/09/2016",
  "07/08/2017",
  "22/07/2017",
  "16/12/2017"
]

dates.sort(function (a, b) {
  arA = a.split("/");
  arB = b.split("/");
  
  return Number(arA[2] + arA[1] + arA[0]) - Number(arB[2] + arB[1] + arB[0]);
});

console.log(dates);
```